# htaccess rewrite whatever to index.php/view/whatever

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want

```
domain.com/whatever
```

To point to

```
domain.com/index.php/view/whatever
```

User would still see `domain.com/whatever` in the browser but behind the scenes it would be browsing `domain.com/index.php/view/whatever`.

Comment: Is that last view a parameter to index.php i.e. `index.php?view=` or is `index.php\view` all a directory?

Comment: @ulrich it's as you see it `index.php/view`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in the .htaccess file in the root directory of your domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#for all subdomains of domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php/view.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/view/$1 [L]
```

Comment: OK It's not working properly. If i try to go to `test.doamin.com/whatever`. It should be accessing the page `test.domain.com/index.php/view/whatever`. Is there anything missing.

Comment: I edit the question to a simpler version excluding the sub from the equation. Maybe that helps

Comment: What happens when you go to `test.domain.com.whatever` e.g. do you get a 404? Is the folder `index.php/view/` in root folder of your domain?

Comment: I do not get anything. No errors. view is dynamically generated and not a folder.

Comment: Let's exlude sub and not worry about it as i initially asked. Because the way you have it, if i do not have a sudomain in the url it throws an error, i do not really need the sub part for now.

Comment: Change the first line to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]` for just the domain.

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't solve my question. All i want is for `domain.com/whatever` to point to `domain.com/index.php/view/whatever`